# JSF c:set evaluation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl

```
<c:set var="product" value="#{productDAO.findByCode('code')}"  />
#{product.name}
#{product.name}
```

I would like to retrieve an object from the DB and store into a variable once.
However, I find the call to the DB is made everytime I access product.
In the example above there are two calls to the DB.

Comment: You should not be invoking Model from your View.

Comment: @Ravi Thats not very helpful.

Comment: Any reason why the Model can't fire DAO code and set the bean as View scoped? I'm sure `#{product.name}` would work correctly then.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16268940/1065197. By the way, in JSF, you don't have to set a variable using JSTL + EL, this will just lead to other problems since `#{product.name}` can't be set to anything since it defines a deferred evaluation expression. Refer to [StackOverflow EL wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984/1065197)

Comment: You shuold understand JSF MVC structure well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111387/understanding-jsf-as-a-mvc-framework

Answer (score 8):

You need to explicitly specify the scope.

```
<c:set var="product" value="#{productDAO.findByCode('code')}" scope="request" />
```

The proper approach, however, is to create and use a request scoped managed bean and put this logic in its `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Without the `scope` attr `product` goes into `Page` scope. How does setting the `scope` to `request` change the current behaviour? Please help understand.

Comment: @Ravi: uh, it goes into request scope.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but how does it prevent the OP's problem? `"I find the call to the DB is made everytime I access product."`

Comment: @Ravi: it's then evaluated once per request instead. Note that the scopeless one represents the `none` scope and then the `<c:set>` acts merely as an "alias". The underlying EL expression is then still evaluated everytime the variable is referenced. Run a debugger to see it yourself.

Comment: DD: I think @BalusC answer solves your problem (it solved mine), if so then it would be good if you could accept the answer .. some housekeeping please ..